# insert adjacent and calculation with javascript

Tags: javascript

can me someone explain how i don't get the string of the numbers, but the result from plus?

Here my code:

```
var pr01 = 1.8;
var pr02 = 2.6;
//for field one 
        document.all.PRI.insertAdjacentText("BeforeEnd", pr01);


//for field two
        document.all.PRI.insertAdjacentText("BeforeEnd", pr02);
```

Comment: What is the expected result exactly and what is the result you are seeing right now? e.g. *I expect to see 1.8 but I see undefined instead* or whatever

Comment: the result now is 1.82.6 but i want to see 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pr01 = 1.8;
var pr02 = 2.6;

document.all.PRI.insertAdjacentText("BeforeEnd", pr01 + pr02);
```

Comment: that is to simple ;-) there are two div tags (fields) like that: <p id="zut01" onclick="insert ();"></p> and <p id="zut02" onclick="insert ();"></p>

Comment: @Potator well it appears you have misrepresented your question then.. given your question and expectations this is the solution =X